# TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0. TypeError: 'KeyError' object is not iterable

Tags: torch, keyerror, torchvision

```
from torchvision_starter.engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
from torchvision_starter import utils
import multiprocessing
import time

n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')


_ = model.to(device)

params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)

lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                               step_size=3,
                                               gamma=0.2,
                                               verbose=True
                                              )
# Let's train for 10 epochs
num_epochs = 1

start = time.time()

for epoch in range(10, 10 + num_epochs):
    # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loaders['train'], device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    # update the learning rate
    lr_scheduler.step()
    # evaluate on the validation dataset
    evaluate(model, data_loaders['valid'], device=device)

stop = time.time()

print(f"\n\n{num_epochs} epochs in {stop - start} s ({(stop-start) / 3600:.2f} hrs)")
```

Before I move on to this part, everything is OK. But after I run the part, the error is like below:
[image]
[image]

I have tried to add drop_last to the helper.py's function like:

```
data_loaders["train"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_data,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        sampler=train_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn,
        drop_last=True
    )
```

But it doesn't work. By the way, the torch and torchvision are compatible and Cuda is available.
I wonder how to fix it.

The get_data_loaders function:

```
def get_data_loaders(
    folder, batch_size: int = 2, valid_size: float = 0.2, num_workers: int = -1, limit: int = -1, thinning: int = None
):
    """
    Create and returns the train_one_epoch, validation and test data loaders.

    :param foder: folder containing the dataset
    :param batch_size: size of the mini-batches
    :param valid_size: fraction of the dataset to use for validation. For example 0.2
                       means that 20% of the dataset will be used for validation
    :param num_workers: number of workers to use in the data loaders. Use -1 to mean
                        "use all my cores"
    :param limit: maximum number of data points to consider
    :param thinning: take every n-th frame, instead of all frames
    :return a dictionary with 3 keys: 'train_one_epoch', 'valid' and 'test' containing respectively the
            train_one_epoch, validation and test data loaders
    """

    if num_workers == -1:
        # Use all cores
        num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    # We will fill this up later
    data_loaders = {"train": None, "valid": None, "test": None}

    # create 3 sets of data transforms: one for the training dataset,
    # containing data augmentation, one for the validation dataset
    # (without data augmentation) and one for the test set (again
    # without augmentation)
    data_transforms = {
        "train": get_transform(UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.mean, UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.std, train=True),
        "valid": get_transform(UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.mean, UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.std, train=False),
        "test": get_transform(UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.mean, UdacitySelfDrivingDataset.std, train=False),
    }

    # Create train and validation datasets
    train_data = UdacitySelfDrivingDataset(
        folder, 
        transform=data_transforms["train"], 
        train=True,
        thinning=thinning
    )
    
    # The validation dataset is a split from the train_one_epoch dataset, so we read
    # from the same folder, but we apply the transforms for validation
    valid_data = UdacitySelfDrivingDataset(
        folder, 
        transform=data_transforms["valid"], 
        train=True,
        thinning=thinning
    )

    # obtain training indices that will be used for validation
    n_tot = len(train_data)
    indices = torch.randperm(n_tot)

    # If requested, limit the number of data points to consider
    if limit > 0:
        indices = indices[:limit]
        n_tot = limit

    split = int(math.ceil(valid_size * n_tot))
    train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]

    # define samplers for obtaining training and validation batches
    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    valid_sampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)  # =

    # prepare data loaders
    data_loaders["train"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_data,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        sampler=train_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn,
        drop_last=True
    )
    data_loaders["valid"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        valid_data,  # -
        batch_size=batch_size,  # -
        sampler=valid_sampler,  # -
        num_workers=num_workers,  # -
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn,
        drop_last=True
    )

    # Now create the test data loader
    test_data = UdacitySelfDrivingDataset(
        folder, 
        transform=data_transforms["test"], 
        train=False,
        thinning=thinning
    )

    if limit > 0:
        indices = torch.arange(limit)
        test_sampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(indices)
    else:
        test_sampler = None

    data_loaders["test"] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        test_data, 
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        shuffle=False, 
        num_workers=num_workers, 
        sampler=test_sampler, 
        collate_fn=utils.collate_fn,
        drop_last=True
        # -
    )

    return data_loaders
```

```
class UdacitySelfDrivingDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    # Mean and std of the dataset to be used in nn.Normalize
    mean = torch.tensor([0.3680, 0.3788, 0.3892])
    
    std = torch.tensor([0.2902, 0.3069, 0.3242])
    
    def __init__(self, root, transform, train=True, thinning=None):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.root = os.path.abspath(os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(root)))
        self.transform = transform
        
        # load datasets
        if train:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.root, "labels_train.csv"))
        else:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.root, "labels_test.csv"))
        
        # Index by file id (i.e., a sequence of the same length as the number of images)
        codes, uniques = pd.factorize(self.df['frame'])
        
        if thinning:
            # Take every n-th rows. This makes sense because the images are
            # frames of videos from the car, so we are essentially reducing
            # the frame rate
            thinned = uniques[::thinning]
            idx = self.df['frame'].isin(thinned)
            print(f"Keeping {thinned.shape[0]} of {uniques.shape[0]} images")
            print(f"Keeping {idx.sum()} objects out of {self.df.shape[0]}")
            self.df = self.df[idx].reset_index(drop=True)
            
            # Recompute codes
            codes, uniques = pd.factorize(self.df['frame'])
        
        self.n_images = len(uniques)
        self.df['image_id'] = codes
        self.df.set_index("image_id", inplace=True)
        
        self.classes = ['car', 'truck', 'pedestrian', 'bicyclist', 'light']
        self.colors = ['cyan', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'orange']
    @property
    def n_classes(self):
        return len(self.classes)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        if idx in self.df.index:
            row = self.df.loc[[idx]]
        else:
            return KeyError(f"Element {idx} not in dataframe")
        
        # load images fromm file
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "images", row['frame'].iloc[0])
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        
        # Exclude bogus boxes with 0 height or width
        h = row['ymax'] - row['ymin']
        w = row['xmax'] - row['xmin']
        filter_idx = (h > 0) & (w > 0)
        row = row[filter_idx]
        
        # get bounding box coordinates for each mask
        boxes = row[['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']].values

        # convert everything into a torch.Tensor
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        
        # get the labels
        labels = torch.as_tensor(row['class_id'].values, dtype=int)

        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        
        # assume no crowd for everything
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((row.shape[0],), dtype=torch.int64)

        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

        if self.transform is not None:
            img, target = self.transform(img, target)

        return img, target

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_images
    
    def plot(self, idx, renormalize=True, predictions=None, threshold=0.5, ax=None):
        
        image, label_js = self[idx]
        
        if renormalize:
            
            # Invert the T.Normalize transform
            unnormalize = T.Compose(
                [
                    T.Normalize(mean = [ 0., 0., 0. ], std = 1 / type(self).std),
                    T.Normalize(mean = -type(self).mean, std = [ 1., 1., 1. ])
                ]
            )

            image, label_js = unnormalize(image, label_js)
        
        if ax is None:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
        
        _ = ax.imshow(torch.permute(image, [1, 2, 0]))
        
        for i, box in enumerate(label_js['boxes']):
            
            xy = (box[0], box[1])
            h, w = (box[2] - box[0]), (box[3] - box[1])
            r = patches.Rectangle(xy, h, w, fill=False, color=self.colors[label_js['labels'][i]-1], lw=2, alpha=0.5)
            ax.add_patch(r)
        
        if predictions is not None:
            
            # Make sure the predictions are on the CPU
            for k in predictions:
                predictions[k] = predictions[k].detach().cpu().numpy()
            
            for i, box in enumerate(predictions['boxes']):
                
                if predictions['scores'][i] > threshold:
                    xy = (box[0], box[1])
                    h, w = (box[2] - box[0]), (box[3] - box[1])
                    r = patches.Rectangle(xy, h, w, fill=False, color=self.colors[predictions['labels'][i]-1], lw=2, linestyle=':')
                    ax.add_patch(r)
        
        _ = ax.axis("off")
        
        return ax
```